# How can I execute JS on server-side?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee

I'm on a Java EE project and I need to use the value of a JS var on my Java code but my java code is execute before my JS (logic)

But I need the value of a JS var to execute my java and I think it will work if I execute my js on server-side but I don't know how to do this ...

My code is something like this :
JS :

```
function(){
var url = "an url of 20.000 char that I can't pass in GET and who is automatically generated by google chart API"
}
```

Java :

```
<%
String urlChart = "value of my "url" var in js";
session.setAttribute("urlChart", urlChart); 
%>
```

But I don't know how tu put the value of my JS var un my java code. Can you help me ? 
Somebody said me that I have to use AJAX but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I want to export a google chart in a pdf file and when I creating an image of my chart (in JS) the URL of it is long of more than 20.000 caracter so I can't pass it to my export page in the URL (And I have 4 chart to export ...)

Comment: You could create the [chart on server](http://code.google.com/p/googlechartwrapper/) side too.

Comment: @stefan I can't create my charts on server side, in this case I have just 4 charts but I want to use the PDF export with my chart on a lot of jsp page who contain charts so I can't remake all of them.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in my understanding. you must switch to some other alternate solutions. you can use CGI or PHP or AJAX.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Their web app is written in Java.  Why should they use PHP?

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I wanted to write this ;) I just want to pass the value between two JSP page (one where the javascript code is execute and create my var and the other who generate My PDF file)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this similiar question: [how to send a string to a servlet from javascript using xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355435/how-to-send-a-string-to-a-servlet-from-javascript-using-xmlhttprequest)

If this won't help, then you need to provide more details because i'm not sure if i understand your problem.